# My Shellcode is in a non-executable part of a Windows executable. Is there still a way to execute it?

Tags: ollydbg, exploit, binary

I'm trying to exploit a test server executable that holds some user-controlled data in memory. I can gain control of EIP and go there, however I get an access violation in OllyDBG because it's not executable.

Is there a way to get around this without directly editing the executable?

Comment: Probably, but the question needs more information to provide a good answer. Are there any other protections on the executable (e.g., ASLR, etc.)? How exactly are you getting control of EIP (e.g., stack buffer overflow, heap overflow, type confusion, use-after-free, etc.)?

Answer (score 2):

well, you can’t execute non-executable pages, so you have the following options:

- use an executable memory area for your shellcode if available.
- somehow force the program to mark the memory with shellcode as executable
- use ROP (return-oriented programming) instead of straight executable shellcode. The ROP payload does not need to be executable since it borrows executable gadgets from the existing code areas in the process.